# Translate minicart , captcha module and other module Magento2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, captcha, translate

I have a website with 3 differents language : arabic, french , english. i created the i18n under my

> app/code/Maget/MyModule/i18n

but there is the minicart, captcha module, strength of password and other text not translated to the french none to arabic. Can any one explain to me how to create and install the french and arabic patch of translation step by step?